# Amalgamating SQL queries stored as views together / Combining tables

Tags: sql, view, sql-server-2012

I have several summary queries stored as Views...

[image]

...and would like to join them together into one combined output as follows:

[image]

..so I can use it as a pivot table in Excel.

**Date** is the only common denominator in the case.

I can do this in Excel using SUMIFS but would prefer to manage it in the SQL before it arrives in Excel.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which database product are you using? Access? SQL Server? mysql? Oracle? Other?

Comment: Is there _anything_ to order by or is any region valid for any R_Qty for example? Also, are we talking SQL Server or something else?

Comment: Related to @JoachimIsaksson's question, how do we know that `View3.Bed=1` and `View3.R_Qty=15` go with `View1.Dogs=1` and `View1.D_Qty=5` and not, for example, with `View1.Dogs=2` and `View1.D_Qty=10`? Both possible pairings match on the dates.

Comment: I use MS SQL Server 2012 so SQL Server I guess..

Comment: Can order by Date, as per the 2nd picture.  Qty values are specific to the previous column, ie D_Qty for Dogs, R_Qty for Regions etc..

Comment: Essentially each view table is separate and needs to be kept so, I just want to lay them side by side and line them up with the dates as the common denominator.  Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for the answers Mike. Stitching these tables together will need some kind of ordering besides the date. When two rows in `View2`, for example, have the same `Date`, how should they be ordered? Why does `France/40` come before `Spain/50`?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Ordering France/40 and Spain/50 is of no importance as the pivot table in Excel will just work on showing one value OR another based on dates.  So we can order ASC on Region or R_Qty, but R_Qty will always apply to that Region.  No Regions are duplicated for the same date, so there will always be just one France for 1/8/13 etc.. Same for all Views. ;-)

Comment: RE @Hiren gardhariya below - I can add another column to the views if necessary, can it be just 1's or is something else preferable?  Still need to see how I would combine them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a matching ID, the best I can think of is to order by `ROW_NUMBER()`, which gives a slightly verbose query;

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE 
                               ORDER BY CASE WHEN Dogs IS NULL THEN 1 END) r1 
  FROM View1
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE 
                               ORDER BY CASE WHEN Region IS NULL THEN 1 END) r2
  FROM View2
), cte3 AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE 
                               ORDER BY CASE WHEN Bed IS NULL THEN 1 END) r3
  FROM View3
)
SELECT COALESCE(cte1.Date, cte2.Date, cte3.Date) Date, 
                Dogs, D_Qty, Region, R_Qty, Bed, B_Qty
FROM cte1
FULL OUTER JOIN cte2
  ON cte1.Date = cte2.Date AND r1=r2
FULL OUTER JOIN cte3
  ON cte1.Date = cte3.Date AND r1=r3
  OR cte2.Date = cte3.Date AND r2=r3
ORDER BY Date, COALESCE(r1,r2,r3)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01df3/5).

You may consider adding an order column to your views, using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE ORDER BY (whatever order is in them)`, that would eliminate all the cte's and give you a stable ordering of things.

Answer (score 0):

if you can Add one more column in your view1 and view2 and view3 than you can solve your issue easily,

[Check this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8421d/2)

Comment: in this case you need always more id in view3 table.